# Polygon fill outside of stroke in print composer

Tags: qgis, style, legend, icon

For some reason the polygon fill is outside of the stroke in QGIS print composer. My stroke width is set to 0.18 which I would like to keep constant. Is there anyway to fix so that the stroke goes on top of the polygon fill?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Fixed - see image. The outside was below the fill in the symbol selector.

[image]